# Oracle - SQL - insert into with sub select

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm getting `ORA-00947: not enough values` from the query below:

```
insert into tableb
(colA, colb, colc, cold)
select
(select max(rec_no)+1 from tableb)
F2,
F3,
F4
from tablea;
```

Can someone point me to the correct way to include a sub query for an inser into/select statement?

Thanks

Comment: I hope you are not trying to create a unique ID using that `max()` approache. Because it will simply not work. Better use a sequence

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name actually this is what I was attempting. Can you provide a link to a discussion about how I'd achieve this with a sequence? Thanks

Comment: See my answer. The sequence still won't solve the problem what to do if tablea is empty (as David Aldridge mentioned)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are just missing a comma. As it is, Oracle thinks `F2` is the name of your sub-select.

```
insert into tableb
(colA, colb, colc, cold)
select
(select max(rec_no)+1 from tableb) ,   -- comma here
F2,
F3,
F4
from tablea;
```

Comment: Thank you! I was going crazy!

Comment: Won't work if there are no rows in the table to begin with, or multiple sessions are running that code at the same time. Unfortunately the approach is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: @David Aldridge the tables aren't empty, I'm the only one running this code. Is there a better method?

Comment: If you want to generate unique record numbers, consider using a sequence.

Answer (score 8):

The only reliable, fast and scalable way to generate unique IDs is using sequences.

The reason why the `max()` "solution" won't work, is a transaction will not see uncommitted changes from another transaction. So two concurrent transactions can wind up using the same value for `max()` which in turn will generate duplicate id values.

To create the values from a sequence in your case, you obviously need to first create a sequence:

```
create sequence seq_b;
```

Then use that sequence in your select statement:

```
insert into tableb
  (colA, colb, colc, cold)
select seq_b.nextval,
       F2,
       F3,
       F4
from tablea;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explantion and the help.